# phpunit is installed but mac isn't recognizing

Tags: macos, installation, phpunit

[image: Terminal Screenshot]
I installed phpunit as you can see in the terminal pic, but when I try to run something with it I get the message that it is not installed. On a mac mini osx 10.9.4 and this did work on my macbook pro. Can't figure out why not now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was actually this that worked and thanks @STLMikey for the suggestion:

chmod +x phpunit.phar

sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit

the difference from using the phpunit website install was just by using sudo!

Answer (score 0):

If using a phar, this commaind:

```
php phpunit.phar
```

should do what you want.